# how to loop a dict in a {} using python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This is my code :

```
a = {0:'000000',1:'11111',3:'333333',4:'444444'}

b = {i:j+'www'  for i,j in a.items()}
print b
```

and it shows error :

```
  File "g.py", line 7
    b = {i:j+'www'  for i,j in a.items()}
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{i:j+'www'  for i,j in a.items()}
```

[Dictionary Comprehension](http://diveintopython3.org/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension) works fine in Python 3.

As you can see here: http://ideone.com/tbXLA (note, I am calling print as a function in Python 3).

If you have < Python 3, then it will give you this error.

To do this type of concept, you must do list/generator expression which creates a tuple of key, value. Once this happens, you can call dict() which accepts a list of tuples.

```
dict((i,j+'www') for i,j in a.items())
```

Comment: But in Python 3, you have to use print as a function: print(b)

Comment: [Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html) also has dictionary comprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

```
b = {i:j+'www'  for i,j in a.items()} #will work in python3+
```

The above is a `dict` comprehension (note curly braces). They have been introduced in Python3.
I guess you are using Python2.x which supports only `list` comprehensions.

```
b = dict( (i:j+'www')  for i,j in a.items() ) #will work in python2.4+
          <-----generator exression------->
```

[More on generators.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)